# Failed to establish connection with 'nominatim.openstreetmap.org'. Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, nominatim, geopy

For some reason I cannot establish connection with nominatim.openstreetmap.org. Error texts says Max retries exceeded with url but it works fine on my Jupyter Notebook. The issue comes when I run my code in visual studio.

```
def get_zip_code(self,x):
geolocator = geopy.geocoders.Nominatim(user_agent="check")
location = geolocator.reverse("{}, {}".format(x['LATITUDE'],x['LONGITUDE']))
return location.raw['address']['postcode']
```

Error:

geopy.exc.GeocoderUnavailable:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nominatim.openstreetmap.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /reverse?lat=38.75246&lon=-90.37342&format=json&addressdetails=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000029697ED9670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted'))

I do not fully understand where this error comes from?

Comment: Maybe you break some usage policy principles https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/.

Comment: I have checked and it does not look like I did.

Comment: `Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted` suggests you are making multiple simultaneous connections, instead of one at a time. Tweak your code to not automatically try again

Comment: I have tried to do that but I can't make it work. Any suggestion?